postgresql NESTED transactions with LOCKS
i have a modular event driven monolith application written with nestJs i have module A, B and C.
Module A will emit an event, both module B and C will listen to that event, they will both share the same global transaction for data consistency, but each of module B and C will need to isolate the changes made by it, so each of them should use transactions, we call them Transaction B and C respectively
1st, does postgresql support nested transactions with typeorm?
2nd, how can the database differentiate between the queries meant for transaction B and queries for Transaction C given that the two modules wont wait for each other to complete the processing to finish?
3rd, can two sub-transactions acctually lock rows from each other?
i tried running nested transactions, but i am sure that i am not doing anything that will help postgresql know which query is for which transaction.
Note: i know what are savepoints, but savepoints does not work on race conditions and does not have locks.

What you imagine cannot be. If you could have independent, concurrent subtransactions of a single transaction, then rolling back a subtransaction could lead to inconsistencies, if the actions of other subtransactions depend on the work done by the subtransaction that was rolled back.
You need to use different database sessions and transactions for concurrent database activity. If you need to coordinate the transactions, you need to use prepared transactions and the two-phase commit protocol. Be warned that you need a crash-safe transaction coordinator if you do that, otherwise stale prepared transactions will bring your database down. And yes, these transactions would lock each other.
But perhaps you should consider a simpler solution, like not using events to coordinate different processes, and instead use a simple database trigger, which is guaranteed to run in the same transaction as the triggering statement.  If that is undesirable, because the triggered activity takes a long time, reconsider the requirement to have both run in the same transaction. It will lead to pain and suffering.

1st, what you mentioned as not possible is indeed not possible in PostgreSQL, but it is technically feasible if someone puts effort into it.
each subtransaction can see the data of the parent transaction, but act as different normal transactions with other subtransactions.
the solution I am opting for is optimistic locking at the application -ORM- level or forcing the processing of the event to be serial so that no two modules in the same transaction can run concurrently.
